# Validate checkbox before calling ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a repeater:

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat="worktime in workTimesFiltered ">
```

Inside the repeater I have an input checkbox:

```
 <input ng-change="updateIncludeOnInvoice(worktime.includeOnInvoice, worktime.timeType)" name='obj1_data' type="checkbox" ng-model="worktime.includeOnInvoice" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false">
```

When it's checked I call updateIncludeOnInvoice. The problem is that I don't want it to be clickable if another worktime.timeType == "0%".

I can capture this in updateIncludeOnInvoice and have tried setting worktime.includeOnInvoice = false, but the checkbox remains on screen.

I have found a way to get access to the dom element that was clicked to manually set it back to unchecked, but it seems hacky....

What's the correct way of dealing with this?

Validate checkbox somehow before calling ng-change, if so how?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this you just want to disable the checkbox when some condition is met.

```
        <input ng-disabled="isConditionMet()">

        $scope.isConditionMet = function() {
           // check your condition and return true/false
        };
```